# Symfony AJAX comment system with votes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ecmascript-6, ajax

How can I improve this code ? It was quite hard to implement AJAX comment system in Symfony 3, and result is a bit of mess:

**Controller:**

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\Article;
use AppBundle\Entity\ArticleCategory;
use AppBundle\Entity\Comment;
use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use AppBundle\Entity\UserLikedArticles;
use AppBundle\Form\CommentFormType;
use AppBundle\Repository\ArticleRepository;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/articles/{category}", name="articles")
     */
    public function getArticles(string $category) : object
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $categoryId = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:ArticleCategory')->getCategoryIdByCode($category);
        $articles = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Article')->findAllByCategory((int)$categoryId);
        return $this->render('articles/articles.html.twig', [
            'articles' => $articles
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/articles/{category}/{id}", name="article")
     */
    public function getArticle($category, $id)
    {
        $isFavourite = false;
        $isLikedArticle = false;
        $isUnlikedArticle = false;

        $articleRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Article::class);
        $article = $articleRepo->find($id);

        $categoryRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(ArticleCategory::class);
        $categories = $categoryRepo->findAll();

        $categoryId = $categoryRepo->getCategoryIdByCode($category);
        $lastArticles = $articleRepo->getLimitArticlesByCategory((int)$categoryId, 3);

        $nextArticle = $articleRepo->getNextArticle((int)$categoryId, $id);
        $previousArticle = $articleRepo->getPreviousArticle((int)$categoryId, $id);

        if ($this->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
            $userRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class);
            $user = $this->getUser();
            $user = $userRepo->find($user->getId());
            $userFavouriteArticles = $user->getFavouriteArticles();

            $userLikedArticle = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:UserLikedArticles')
                ->findOneBy(array(
                    'userId' => $user,
                    'articleId' => $article,
                ));

            if ($userLikedArticle) {
                $userLikedArticle->getAppraisal() == 'like' ? $isLikedArticle = true : $isUnlikedArticle = true;
            }

            foreach ($userFavouriteArticles as $userFavouriteArticle) {
                if ($userFavouriteArticle->getId() == $id) {
                    $isFavourite = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (is_null($nextArticle)) {
            $nextArticle = $articleRepo->getRandomArticle((int)$categoryId, $id);
        }

        if (is_null($previousArticle)) {
            $previousArticle = $articleRepo->getRandomArticle((int)$categoryId, $id);
        }

        $commentForm = $this->createForm(CommentFormType::class);

        return $this->render('articles/article.html.twig', [
            'article' => $article,
            'categories' => $categories,
            'lastArticles' => $lastArticles,
            'nextArticle' => $nextArticle,
            'previousArticle' => $previousArticle,
            'commentForm' => $commentForm->createView(),
            'isFavourite' => $isFavourite,
            'isLikedArticle' => $isLikedArticle,
            'isUnlikedArticle' => $isUnlikedArticle
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/articles/{category}/{id}/addcomment/{replyToId}", defaults={"replyToId"=0}, name="addcomment")
     */
    public function addComment(Request $request, $category, $id, $replyToId)
    {
        $status = 'error';
        $message = '';

        if (!$this->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
            echo 'ne e lognat'; exit;
            $message = 'Трябва да се логнете, за да добавите нов коментар!';
        } else {
            $form = $this->createForm(CommentFormType::class);

            $form->handleRequest($request);
            if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

                $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AppBundle:User")->find($this->getUser()->getId());

                $comment = $form->getData();
                $comment->setPerson($user);
                $comment->setReplyTo($replyToId);
                $comment->setPostId($id);
                $comment->setDateAdded(new \DateTime("now"));

                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $article = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Article')->find($id);
                $article->setComments($article->getComments() + 1);
                $em->persist($article);
                $em->persist($comment);
                try {
                    $em->flush();
                    $status = "success";
                    $message = "new comment was saved";
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $message = $e->getMessage();
                }
            }
        }

        $response = array(
            'status' => $status,
            'message' => $message,
        );

        return new JsonResponse($response);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/articles/{category}/{id}/addanswer/{replyToId}", defaults={"replyToId"=0}, name="addanswer")
     */
    public function addAnswer(Request $request, $category, $id, $replyToId)
    {
        $status = 'error';
        $message = '';

        if (!$this->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
            echo 'ne e lognat'; exit;
            $message = 'Трябва да се логнете, за да добавите нов отговор!';
        } else {
            $comment = new Comment();
            $comment->setContent($request->request->get('textarea-answer'));
            $comment->setPersonId($this->getUser()->getId());
            $comment->setReplyTo($replyToId);
            $comment->setPostId($id);
            $comment->setDateAdded(new \DateTime("now"));

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($comment);
            try {
                $em->flush();
                $status = "success";
                $message = "new answer was saved";
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $message = $e->getMessage();
            }
        }

        $response = array(
            'status' => $status,
            'message' => $message,
        );

        return new JsonResponse($response);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/articles/{category}/{id}/true/{page}", defaults={"page"=1}, name="articleAjax")
     */
    public function getArticleAjax($category, $id, $page)
    {
        $recordsPerPage = 10;
        $offset = ($page-1) * $recordsPerPage;

        $commentRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Comment::class);

        $countRecords = $commentRepo->countRecords($id);
        $totalPages = ceil($countRecords / $recordsPerPage);

        $articleRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Article::class);
        $article = $articleRepo->find($id);

        $comments = $commentRepo->getPaginationPost($recordsPerPage, $offset, $id);

        foreach ($comments as &$comment) {
            $subcomments = $commentRepo->getSubComments($comment['id']);
            $comment['subComments'] = $subcomments;
        }

        $response = [
            'comments' => $comments,
            'id' => $id,
            'totalPages' => $totalPages
        ];

        return new JsonResponse($response);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("subcomments/{commentId}/{lastAnswer}/{step}", defaults={"step"=2}, name="getSubcomments")
     */
    public function getMoreAnswers($commentId, $lastAnswer, $step)
    {
        $limit = 2;
        $commentRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Comment::class);
        $answers = $commentRepo->getMoreAnswers($commentId, $lastAnswer, $step, $limit);

        $step = $step+2;

        $response = [
            'answers' => $answers,
            'step' => $step
        ];

        return new JsonResponse($response);

    }

    /**
     * @Route("/articles/{category}/{id}/addtofavorites", name="addToFavourites")
     */
    public function addToFavourites($category, $id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $article = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Article")->find($id);
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $user = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:User")->find($user->getId());
        if (!$user->addFavouriteArticle($article)) {
            $article->setFavourites($article->getFavourites() - 1);
        } else {
            $article->setFavourites($article->getFavourites() + 1);
        }
        $em->persist($article);
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

        $test = 'true';

        return new JsonResponse($test);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/articles/{category}/{id}/likeunlike/{type}", name="likeUnlike")
     */
    public function likeUnlikeAction($category, $id, $type)
    {
        $isLikedUnliked = false;

        $type == 'like' ? $otherType = 'unlike' : $otherType = 'like';

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $article = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Article")->find($id);

        $user = $this->getUser();
        $user = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:User")->find($user->getId());

        $UserLikedArticle = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:UserLikedArticles')
            ->findOneBy(array(
                'userId' => $user,
                'articleId' => $article,
                'appraisal' => $type
            ));

        $userOtherTypeLikedArticle = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:UserLikedArticles')
            ->findOneBy(array(
                'userId' => $user,
                'articleId' => $article,
                'appraisal' => $otherType
            ));

        if ($type == 'like') {
            if ($UserLikedArticle) {
                $em->remove($UserLikedArticle);
                $em->flush();
                $article->setLikes($article->getLikes() - 1);
            } else {
                $userLikedArticles = new UserLikedArticles();
                $userLikedArticles->setUserId($user);
                $userLikedArticles->setArticleId($article);
                $userLikedArticles->setAppraisal($type);
                $article->setLikes($article->getLikes() + 1);

                if ($userOtherTypeLikedArticle) {
                    $em->remove($userOtherTypeLikedArticle);
                    $article->setLikes($article->getLikes() + 1);
                }

                $em->persist($userLikedArticles);
                $em->flush();
                $isLikedUnliked = true;
            }

        } else {
            if ($UserLikedArticle) {
                $em->remove($UserLikedArticle);
                $em->flush();
                $article->setLikes($article->getLikes() + 1);
            } else {
                $userLikedArticles = new UserLikedArticles();
                $userLikedArticles->setUserId($user);
                $userLikedArticles->setArticleId($article);
                $userLikedArticles->setAppraisal($type);
                $article->setLikes($article->getLikes() - 1);

                if ($userOtherTypeLikedArticle) {
                    $em->remove($userOtherTypeLikedArticle);
                    $article->setLikes($article->getLikes() - 1);
                }

                $em->persist($userLikedArticles);
                $em->flush();
                $isLikedUnliked = true;
            }
        }

        $em->persist($article);
        $em->flush();

        $likes = $article->getLikes();

        return new JsonResponse($likes);

    }
}
```

**JS:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    loadComments(window.location.href + '/true', '', '');

    //Add / Remove Favourties
    $(".heart.fa").click(function() {

        var url = $('#add-favourite-button').data('link');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            success: function(data)
            {
                $('#add-favourite-button').toggleClass("fa-heart fa-heart-o");
            }
        });


    });

    //Like / Unlike
    $(".glyphicon-arrow-up, .glyphicon-arrow-down").click(function () {

        var button = $(this);
        var type = button.attr("data-type");
        var url = window.location.href + '/likeunlike/' + type;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            success: function(data)
            {
                if (button.attr('id') == 'button-like-article') {
                    $("#button-like-article").toggleClass("orange-arrow");
                    $('#button-unlike-article').removeClass("orange-arrow");
                } else {
                    $("#button-unlike-article").toggleClass("orange-arrow");
                    $("#button-like-article").removeClass("orange-arrow");
                }
                $('#likes-count').text(data);
            }
        });
    });


    // Send comment client logic
    $("#comment_box").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        var url = form.attr('action');

        var category = url.split('/')[2];
        var article = url.split('/')[3];

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(data)
            {
                loadComments('', category, article);
            }
        });
    });

    // Send answer client logic
    $(document).on("click", "#saveButtonAnswer", function (e) {
        $(".answer_box").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = $(this);
            var url = form.attr('action');

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: form.serialize(),
                success: function(data)
                {
                    loadComments(window.location.href + '/true', '', '');
                }
            });
            });
    });

    // Show / Hide form for comment
    $(document).on("click", ".reply", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var commentId = $(this).attr('href');
        $("#post-comment"+commentId).toggle();
    });

    // Show More answers client logic
    $(document).on("click", ".show-more-answers", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        url = $(this).attr('href');
        console.log(url)    ;
        id = $(this).attr('id');
        commentId = $(this).attr('data-comment-id');
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            success: function(data)
            {
                var html = '';

                var answersArray = Object.keys(data.answers).map(function(key) {
                    return data.answers[key];
                });

                console.log(answersArray);

                for (var i = 0; i < answersArray.length; i++) {
                    html += '<div>' +
                        '<div class="media comment-area">' +
                        '<div class="media-left">' +
                        '<a href="#">' +
                        '<img class="media-object" src="../../images/testimonial-1.jpg" alt="">' +
                        '</a>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="media-body">' +
                        '<a class="media-heading" href="#">Prodip Ghosh</a>' +
                        '<h5>Oct 18, 2016</h5>' +
                        '<p>' + answersArray[i].content + '</p>' +
                        '</div>';

                            if ((answersArray[answersArray.length - 1] === answersArray[i])) {
                                html += '<a href="/subcomments/' + commentId + '/' + answersArray[i].id + '/' + data.step + '" class="show-more-answers" id="show-more-answers' + answersArray[i].id + '" data-comment-id="' + commentId + '">Show More</a>';
                            }

                    html += '</div>';
                }

                $('#'+id).after(html);
                $('#'+id).remove();
            }
        });
    });

    $(document).on("click", "#pagination-link", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        loadComments(url);
    });

    // Send comment client logic
    function loadComments (url = '', category = '', article = '', step = 1) {
        var html = '';
        url = (url != '' ? url : '/articles/' + category + '/' + article + '/true');

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            success: function(data)
            {
                var image = "../../images/testimonial-4.jpg";
                data.comments.forEach(function(comment) {
                    html +=
                    '<div class="comment_area">' +
                        '<div class="media">' +
                        '<div class="media-left">' +
                            '<a href="#">' +
                                '<img class="media-object" src="' + image + '" alt="">' +
                            '</a>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '<div class="media-body" id="comment-div">' +
                        '<a class="media-heading" href="/profile/' + comment.person.id + '">' + comment.person.firstName + '</a>' +
                        '<h5>Oct 18, 2016</h5>' +
                        '<p>' + comment.content + '</p>' +
                        '<a class="reply" href="' + comment.id + '">Отговори</a>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="post_comment" id="post-comment' + comment.id + '" style="display: none;">' +
                        '<h3>Добави отговор</h3>' +
                        '<form method="POST" class="comment_box answer_box" id="answer-form' + comment.id  + '" action="' + data.id + '\\addanswer\\' + comment.id + '") }}">' +
                            '<textarea id="textarea-answer" name="textarea-answer" class="form-control input_box"></textarea>' +
                            '<button type="submit" id="saveButtonAnswer">Изпрати</button>' +
                        '</form>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>';

                    var subcommentsArray = Object.keys(comment.subComments).map(function(key) {
                        return comment.subComments[key];
                    });
                    var limit = 2;

                    if (subcommentsArray.length > 0) {
                        //var lastSubcomment = subcommentsArray[subcommentsArray.length - 1];
                            for (var i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
                                if (typeof subcommentsArray[i] === 'undefined') {
                                    continue;
                                }
                                html += '<div class="comment_area reply_comment">' +
                                    '<div class="media comment-area">' +
                                        '<div class="media-left">' +
                                            '<a href="#">' +
                                            '<img class="media-object" src="../../images/testimonial-1.jpg" alt="">' +
                                            '</a>' +
                                        '</div>' +
                                        '<div class="media-body">' +
                                            '<a class="media-heading" href="#">' + subcommentsArray[i].person.firstName + '</a>' +
                                            '<h5>Oct 18, 2016</h5>' +
                                            '<p>' + subcommentsArray[i].content + '</p>' +
                                        '</div>' +
                                    '</div>';
                                    if (subcommentsArray.length > limit) {
                                        if (subcommentsArray[limit-1] === subcommentsArray[i]) {
                                            html += '<a href="/subcomments/' + comment.id + '/' + subcommentsArray[i].id + '" class="show-more-answers" id="show-more-answers' + subcommentsArray[i].id + '" data-comment-id="' + comment.id + '">Show More</a>'
                                        }
                                    }
                                html += '</div>';

                            }
                    }
                });

                html += '<ul>';
                for (var i = 1; i <= data.totalPages; i ++) {
                    html += '<li><a href="' + data.id + '/true/' + i + '" id="pagination-link">' + i +'</a></li>';
                }
                html += '</ul>';

                $('.testt').html(html);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**View:**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {% include 'home/header.html.twig' %}

    <!-- Banner area -->
    <section class="banner_area" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
        <h2>Our Blog</h2>
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="active">Blog</a></li>
        </ol>
    </section>
    <!-- End Banner area -->

    <!-- blog area -->
    <section class="blog_all">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row m0 blog_row">
                <div class="col-sm-8 main_blog">
                    <img src="images/blog/blog_hed-1.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="col-xs-1 p0">
                        <div>
                            <button id="button-like-article" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up {{ isLikedArticle ? 'orange-arrow' : '' }}" data-type="like"></button>
                            <p id="likes-count">{{ article.likes }}</p>
                            <button id="button-unlike-article" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down {{ isUnlikedArticle ? 'orange-arrow' : '' }}" data-type="unlike"></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="blog_date">
                            <a href="#">{{ article.dateAdded|date("d") }}</a>
                            <a href="#">{{ article.dateAdded|date("M")|cyrillicMonth }}</a>
                        </div>
                        {% if is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}
                            <div>
                                <i class="{{ isFavourite ? 'heart fa fa-heart' : 'heart fa fa-heart-o' }}" id="add-favourite-button" data-link="{{ path('addToFavourites', {'category':article.category.code, 'id':article.id}) }}"></i>
                            </div>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-11 blog_content">
                        <a class="blog_heading" href="#">{{ article.title }}</a>
                        <a class="blog_admin" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{ article.author }}</a>
                        <ul class="like_share">
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comment" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{ article.comments }}</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{ article.favourites }}</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-share-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <p>{{ article.content }}</p>
                        <!--div class="tag">
                            <h4>TAG</h4>
                            <a href="#">PAINTING</a>
                            <a href="#">CONSTRUCTION</a>
                            <a href="#">PAINTING</a>
                        </div-->
                    </div>
                    <div class="client_text" id="client-text">
                        <img class="img-circle" src="images/testimonial-4.jpg" alt="">
                        <a class="client_name" href="#">Emran Khan</a>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
                        {% if previousArticle is not null and nextArticle is not null %}
                            <a class="control button_all" href="{{ path('article', {'category':previousArticle.category.code, 'id':previousArticle.id}) }}"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ previousArticle.title }}</a>
                            <a class="control button_all" href="{{ path('article', {'category':nextArticle.category.code, 'id':nextArticle.id}) }}">{{ nextArticle.title }} <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="testt">

                    </div>
                    <div class="post_comment">
                        <h3>Добави коментар</h3>
                        {{ form_start(commentForm, {'action': path('addcomment', {'category':article.category.code, 'id':article.id})}) }}
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <h4>{{ form_label(commentForm.content) }}</h4>
                                {{ form_widget(commentForm.content) }}
                                {{ form_widget(commentForm.submit) }}
                            </div>
                        {{ form_end(commentForm) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 widget_area">
                    <div class="resent">
                        <h3>Последни теми:</h3>
                        {% for article in lastArticles %}
                        <div class="media">
                            <div class="media-left">
                                <a href="{{ path('article', {'category':article.category.code, 'id':article.id}) }}">
                                    <img class="media-object" src="images/blog/rs-1.jpg" alt="">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <a href="">{{ article.title }}</a>
                                <h6>{{ article.dateAdded|date("M")|cyrillicMonth }} {{ article.dateAdded|date("d") }}, {{ article.dateAdded|date("Y") }}</h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="resent">
                        <h3>Категории</h3>
                        <ul class="architecture">
                            {% for category in categories %}
                                <li><a href="{{ path('articles', {'category':category.code}) }}"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{ category.name }}</a></li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!--div class="resent">
                        <h3>ARCHIVES</h3>
                        <ul class="architecture">
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>February 2016</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>April 2016</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>June 2016</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div-->
                    <div class="search">
                        <input type="search" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                    </div>
                    <!--div class="resent">
                        <h3>Tag</h3>
                        <ul class="tag">
                            <li><a href="#">PAINTING</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">CONSTRUCTION</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Architecture</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Building</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- End blog area -->

    {% include 'home/footer.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}
```

Any advice is welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### PHP

Overall, the methods and functions look a bit long. Look at `ArticleController::getArticle()` - its more than 50 lines! Pretend you are a teammate who has to modify this code without being very familiar with it.

One way to improve things would be to split out blocks of code into separate methods - especially repeated code like the blocks that instantiate and save `Comment` objects. This adheres to the **D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself principle (i.e. **D.R.Y**). You might also aim to keep the indentation level to one and avoid using the `else` keyword, as recommended by Rafael Dohms in [this presentation about cleaning up code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GtB5DAfOWMQ).

---

As was mentioned above, `addAnswer` and `addComment` both manipulate a Comment object in very similar ways - many of the common lines could be abstracted to a separate function. In the image below, blue lines represent identical lines that could be abstracted and the purple line is similar - could be abstracted to use a parameter.

[image]

Also note that the return formats are similar so that could also potentially be abstracted to a separate method.

---

In the method `addComment()` I see the following:

```
public function addComment(Request $request, $category, $id, $replyToId)
    {
        $status = 'error';
        $message = '';

        if (!$this->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
            echo 'ne e lognat'; exit;
            $message = 'Трябва да се логнете, за да добавите нов коментар!';
        } else {
```

When the condition in the `if` block evaluates to `true` then the string literal will be sent to the `echo` and the program will exit, thus making the next line (which sets `$message`) unreachable, and thus superfluous.

---

I see a couple places like

> ```
> $status = 'error';
> ```

And then later on:

> ```
> $status = "success";
> ```

One could argue that those values should be stored in constants

---

There are multiple places where a variable is created and assigned immediately before a return statement - e.g. :

`addToFavourites()`:

> ```
>  $test = 'true';
> return new JsonResponse($test);
> ```

`likeUnlikeAction()`:

> ```
> $likes = $article->getLikes();
> return new JsonResponse($likes);
> ```

There is little point to assigning the value to a variable immediately before it gets used in a return statement. Just use the value in the return statement.

---

#### JS

I see a lot of DOM lookups throughout the various javascript event handlers. Bear in mind that those are not cheap<sup>[1](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX09/T53F)</sup> so it is better to store DOM lookups in a variable (or constant if [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) is used - see last section below for more information).

---

Is there really only one element with the class `testt`? Would there ever be a case where multiple elements with that class would be appropriate? If not, perhaps an *id* attribute should be used instead (including referencing that element in the JavaScript code).

---

I can't tell which version of jQuery is used but as of version 3.0<sup>[2](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)</sup> the following syntax is deprecated:

> ```
> $( document ).ready(function() {
> ```

and can be shortened to

```
$(function() {
```

---

Some places in the JavaScript could be simplified using [partially applied functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Partially_applied_functions)- e.g.:

> ```
> success: function(data)
>             {
>                 loadComments(window.location.href + '/true', '', '');
>             }
> ```

could be simplified to something like:

```
success: loadComments.bind(null, window.location.href + '/true', '', '')
```

---

It appears that there are default parameters used on one JavaScript function definition:

> ```
> function loadComments (url = '', category = '', article = '', step = 1) {
> ```

[This is a feature](http://es6-features.org/#DefaultParameterValues) of [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6), which means that if you are going to use that standard, then you could start using other features like [`const`](http://es6-features.org/#Constants) and [`let`](http://es6-features.org/#Constants) instead of `var` for scoping variables, [arrow functions](http://es6-features.org/#ExpressionBodies), etc.

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX09/T53F</sub>
<sup>2</sup><sub>https://api.jquery.com/ready/</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'd be glad to see more info about Symfony part.

Comment: Okay I added some more aspects about the Symfony part.

Comment: Thank you! Now I can accept your answer :)